# Share deserialization code between generated classes - generics or inheritance injection through partial class?

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization

I have some generated classes (from Xsd.exe) which allow me to serialize/deserialize Xml. One such case is a generated `partial class accidents`

I also have some utility code (see below) which I add to the class in another file. The thing is this code would be identical for every generated class I want to use it with, other than `typeof(accidents)`.

First of all it seemed generics should be usable. But I'm not sure I'd do that. Then I wondered, can I introduce a common base class through my partial class? Or is there some other clever way to do this?

```
public partial class accidents
{
    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(accidents));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }


    #region Serialize/Deserialize
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current accidents object into an XML document
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
    public virtual string Serialize()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamReader != null))
            {
                streamReader.Dispose();
            }
            if ((memoryStream != null))
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you make the Serializer member non-static you can use this.GetType() in stead of typeof(accidents) ... just a thought!

Answer (score 1):

I can offer the following variant. Make a separate class-helper for the serialization.

```
public static class GenericSerializer
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, value);
            return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var acc = new accidents();
var str = GenericSerializer.Serialize(acc);
```

All support serialization code can be completely removed from the generated classes.

Comment: Looks good. I don't know why I felt it _had_ to belong to the class.